# Can I edit Play Books dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, google-play-books

When reading on the Google Play Books app, there can be a lot of names or locations to remember. What would be perfect is a way of editing the dictionary to allow custom entries in which I can enter information about these things.

Although that is the ideal solution, I'm happy for similar things: other apps which give me blank or custom dictionaries that will work with google play books, for example.

I'm not massively familiar with Play Books yet, though I tried achieving this with the note function but it only added the note to that exact word (so later occurances of that word do not show the note).

This might not be possible at all, but any help would be great.